# How to get full message including header from Grails JMS?

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic

I want to get the full message (header & body) from an ActiveMQ connection using Grails and JMS.

The code below just returns the message body.  When I uncomment the "static adapter = " line, I get the header and an abbreviated version of the header.  How do I get the full message?

```
class NrodTmListenerService {
    static exposes = ["jms"]
    static destination = "SOMEDESTINATION"
    static isTopic = true
    //  static adapter = "zeroConversionAdapter"    

    def onMessage(msg) {

        // handle message

        // explicitly return null to prevent unwanted replyTo attempt
        return null
    }
}
```

In my config.groovy:

```
jms {
    adapters {
        zeroConversionAdapter {
            meta {
                parentBean = 'standardJmsListenerAdapter'
            }
            messageConverter = null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?